# Rotate a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a navigation view controller. When i select a tableview cell it push a new ViewController from UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait state.

Now if i Rotate the new ViewController Landscape mode and pop the new ViewController and go back the table view Navigation Controller main page then i can see that, NavigationController main page is its previous UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait mode and i can't see the downstair part of my tableView interface.

How i am gonna fixed this such a way that if i pop up the newViewController, the Main Navigation ViewController page will view such a way that achieve the Orientation mode of newViewController.

That mean's if the newViewController is in landscape mode than the main page will automatically landscape mode and if the newViewController is in Portrait mode then the main Navigation page will be automatically Portrait mode.

Any solution ????

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in all your view controllers (in the navigation stack) implementation files.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    return YES;
}
```